# Where can I start learning to develop Decenteralized apps?

Tags: blockchain, testnets, dapps, metamask, tutorials

I have been trying to understand this development process of making DaPPs using ehtereum from various sources, some of them are outdated because this technology is evolving pretty fast as of now.
Currently, I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f but It is using testnet for syncing blockchain and I am confused because, I have found people refering an alternate for this using metamask. I am a begginer therefore there is lot of confusions. Please suggest some latest resource to follow in order to understand dApps better.

Answer (score 0):

### [ETHEREUM PET SHOP](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop)

In my opinion, one of the best tutorials at this moment.

The tutorial is step-by-step, **up-to-date** and with a very good notes to every step.

In this tutorial you will be introduced to:

- Truffle
- MetaMask
- Ganache

But don't be scared if you are not familiar with some of these names, tutorial shows the full guide how to use any of them!

> This tutorial is meant for those with a basic knowledge of Ethereum and smart contracts, who have some knowledge of HTML and JavaScript, but who are new to dapps.

---

*Based on my experience.*