# How to create your own ERC 721 NFT token

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, cryptokitties, erc-721

I am trying to create my own ERC-721 non fungible token and unable to find any docs, basic code and how to deploy it on a testnet. Could someone share the official specification and an example of how to implement an ERC-721 token?

Comment: To unclose this question, please reword to ask where is the official documenentation for 721 and implementation examples.

Comment: This https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721 is the complete reference implementation of the ERC-721 non-fungible token standard for the Ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most official documentation for this token is the request by itself [on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721).

The author of `Non-fungible Token Standard` is Dieter Shirley. He was **first** to implement it on 20 Sep 2017.

> I am also looking to see if I have basic code, how to deploy it on a testnet.

There are too many good answers on this particular question and there are also multiple ways to do it, I will just leave few links.

- [Tutorial
  (Parity)](https://medium.com/@bleev.in.tech/how-to-deploy-a-smart-contract-to-ethereum-testnet-e34fa5b10dd6)
- [Tutorial (Truffle)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/35550/9938)